# Unity3D how to check Collision with Objects tagged "tag"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

at the moment, I am programming a Game with a **Random GameObject Spawner**. My problem to solve is that I am using `Physics.Checksphere` to Instantiate Objects only if there is no Object at this Point around the radius I want.

**That is my Code for this implementation:**

```
if(!Physics.CheckSphere(pos, spawnCollisionCheckRadius))                //Check Radius at pos
       {
           GameObject actStone = stones[Random.Range(0, stones.Count)]; //Get Random Stone Object from List
           Instantiate(actStone, pos, rot);                             //Spawn Stone
       }
```

So the issue what I actually have I that when I have a Sphere Collider my Code with `Physics.CheckSphere` is not working, because it checks any Collision in this Sphere around the Stone and every time it gets a Collision with my planet. But I need a Collider around my Planet. How can I only check a Collision with a tag for me "Stone" and not all Collisions in this Radius. My thoughts were maybe to use `Physics.OverlapSphere` somehow, but I actually did not know how to implement it. Thank you for help and I hope I can help someone with this Question too in the future!

Comment: there is a layerMask argument in the function. You can use layers for some collisions to be ignored. Check [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a third parameter for the [Physics.CheckSphere](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckSphere.html) function, which is called `layerMask`. You can specify this to selectively ignore colliders.